# Windows speech recognition and Dragon NaturallySpeaking , dictating into two separate text Windows?

Tags: windows, speech

So there are these two programs Windows speech recognition and Dragon NaturallySpeaking. In order to test the accuracy of these two programs and compare them side-by-side I want to run them both at the same time speaking to a microphone and then have them dictate into two separate text boxes. Is there a way to do this with Windows? Is there a way to have each program have its own text box, for example to two notepad windows, and then have each program start writing in its own window?

Answer (score 0):

You could either set up two computers and split the signal from the microphone, or, depending on which version of DNS you have, you might be able to use WSR live while recording the audio and then use the transcribe function in higher-end versions of DNS.

Or, you could save yourself a lot of trouble and just use DNS - it's dramatically superior to WSR in almost all meaningful ways. I broke my hand this summer and had to use WSR for ~10 while waiting for v12 of DNS to be released, and it was terrible. When I finally had DNS loaded and trained, it was unbelievable how accurate it was right out of the box, especially compared to WSR.

Comment: I assume you had to rush off somewhere while in the middle of a sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You could record your voice into an audio file and then get Windows Speech Recognition and Dragon Naturally Speaking to transcribe it. This way you can also measure the performance of each Engine because they won't be sharing CPU resources and so you'll get a more representative idea about their speeds.
for DNS:
http://www.dummies.com/software/dragon-naturallyspeaking/how-to-transcribe-your-recording-with-dragon-naturallyspeaking/

for WSR:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMGIMDf-1Qs

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.